# React - could not send a redux-thunk action with extra argument

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I trying to working with typescript with redux-thunk and redux.
I would like to pass an object to any action (I am using dependency injection and I need to pass an object service or string)

i got this error;

```
  Overload 1 of 2, '(action: AnyAction): AnyAction', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(dispatch: any, getState: AppState, extraArg: string) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
```

it's done as follows:

store.ts:

```
const middlewares = [
    routerMiddleware(history),
    thunkMiddleware.withExtraArgument('bar') as ThunkMiddleware<
      AppState,
      Actions,
      string
    >
  ];
  const middleWareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middlewares);

  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer(history),
    preloadState,
    composeWithDevTools(middleWareEnhancer)
  );
```

my index.ts where I am trying to send action is :

```
(store.dispatch as ThunkDispatch<{}, void, AnyAction>)(getAll());
```

my action file that working:

```
export const getall = () => async (dispatch: any) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: GETALL_REQUEST });
    return dispatch({ type: GETALL_SUCCESS, payload: null });
  } catch (e) {
    return dispatch({ type: GETALL_FAILURE, error: e });
  }
};
```

my action (put part of it) that raises the error

```
export const getAll = () => async (
  dispatch: any,
  getState: AppState,
  extraArg: string
) => {....action logic}
```

then I got the error on:

```
(store.dispatch as ThunkDispatch<{}, void, AnyAction>)(getAll());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to correct the error:

```
(store.dispatch as ThunkDispatch<AppState, string, AnyAction>)(getAll());
```

and

```
export const getAll = () => async (
  dispatch: any,
  getState: () => AppState,
  extraArg: string
) => {....action logic}
```

1. `ThunkDispatch` accepts following type arguments: `S` - state, `E` - extended arg, `A` - action. So your use of `ThunkDispatch` should match types of your state and extended arg.
2. Thunk action is a function which accepts following arguments: `dispatch` is a function, `getState` is also a function which returns state and `extraArg`. So make sure, that `getState` is a function.

To avoid `dispatch` casting I suggest to properly type a store when creating. As you're using `applyMiddleware` which accepts an array, you should pass type argument to it. It accepts type of dispatch which will be used after applying Delawares.

```
const middlewares = [thunk.withExtraArgument("bar")];
const middleWareEnhancer = applyMiddleware<
  ThunkDispatch<AppState, string, Actions>
>(...middlewares);
```

As a result, you'll get a store with properly typed dispatch function. And you'll be able to use it without casting.

```
store.dispatch(getAll());
```

The working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dispatchwithextraarg-ny83x)